# strings in c++ run time error

Tags: c++, string, file

I am working on a c++ program which reads a `string` from a file. At the end of the `string` there are some numbers. My task is to display the `nth` number from the end of the string .

Here is my code. The program accepts a path to a file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    ifstream file;
    int num,i=0,pos;    
    std::string lineBuffer;
    file.open(argv[1],ios::in) ;  
    while (!file.eof()) 
      {
         getline(file, lineBuffer);        
         if (lineBuffer.length() == 0)
              continue; //ignore all empty lines
         else 
           {
             pos=0;            
            std::string str1("");
            std::string str2("");
            std::string final("");
            std::string number("");
            std::string output("");
                while(pos!=(-1))
                {
                  pos=lineBuffer.find(" ");                               
                  str2=lineBuffer.substr(0,1);
                  lineBuffer=lineBuffer.substr(pos+1);
                  final+=str2;
                  i++;
                }
                number=final.substr((i-1));
                num=atoi(number.c_str());
                output=final.substr(i-(num+1),1);
                cout<<output;                            
           }    
      }
      file.close();
       return 0;
}
```

My program gives the correct output for first line in the file. But after that it's giving me a runtime error. I don't know why is this happening.

The file I'm sending to the terminal contains:

```
a b c d 4
b e f g 2
```

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: To start with you should run your program in a debugger. This will tell you _where_ the error is. It will also let you examine variables, so you might be able to figure out _what_ causes the error.

Comment: `while (!file.eof()) {` is broken, `eof()` will not return true until *after* a read is attempted, so you have an off by one error. It is *far* better to write: `while(getline(file, lineBuffer)) {`

Comment: Aside from your specific issue, which I think @Evan solved, I suggest you to solve this problem using stringstreams.

Answer (score 1):

Please run your program in a debugger to understand the specific behavior it is doing.  See where it diverges from what you are expecting.

`gdb` may be simplest and you can get started by Googling "gdb cheatsheet" or so.  Remember to compile with `-g`.

Comment: the program is takin the string for next line also but when the editint on line buffer is taking place for second line its givng error i dnt know how to resolve :(

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `pos` as `size_t` instead of `int` since `std::string::find()` returns `size_t`.

Also, when `std::string::find()` matches nothing, it returns `string::npos` instead of `-1`. Thus, you should compare `pos` against `string::npos` instead of the integer literal `-1`.

Comment: the program is takin the string for next line also but when the editint on line buffer is taking place for second line its givng error i dnt know how to resolve :(